# Trying to add a left join to a LINQ statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to allow `g.CustomerBillId` to pull back nulls in addition to existing logic.

```
var previous = from g in FindAllCustomerPayments(obj.CustomerId)
               join a in custPay                               
               on g.CustomerBillId equals a.CustomerBillId
               where System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(g.TransactionDateTime) <= previousBill.EffectiveDate   
               group g by new
               {
                   CustomerId = g.CustomerId

               } into p
               select new
               {
                   p.Key,
                   previousBalance = p.Sum(n => n.Credit) - p.Sum(n => n.Debit)
               };
```

Comment: Okay, so what does the code you've got give you? (And why are you creating a new anonymous type just for the single customer ID property? Just `group g by g.CustomerId into p` would be fine...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just

```
from a in custPay.where(cust => cust.CustomerBillId = g.CustomerBillId).DefaultIfEmpty()
```